# What is wmain or _tmain alternatives in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, program-entry-point

I want to read some unicode parameters via C++ main function. In Windows I can use wmain which is Mircosoft extension to standard C++. But I don't know to how to do the same in Linux platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux you use the Standard C++ `main` function, and your data will be conveyed through `char const*`.

You should probably expect the encoding to be UTF-8 because this is the default on Linux.